# AES. javax.crypto.Cipher returns empty array in decryption mode

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

I'm implementing CBC mode by myself. And I use AES as an E function for each CBC block.

Here is my encryption code:

```
public static List<Byte> encrypt(List<Byte> bytes, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytesArray = BytesConverter.toByteArray(bytes);

    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

    return BytesConverter.toByteList(cipher.update(bytesArray));
}
```

I use `update` because I don't want to add AES pad. I do it by myself for last block at the begining of CBC algorythm.

When I want to decrypt cyphertext block, I use the same function with Cipher.DECRYPTION_MODE.

```
public static List<Byte> decrypt(List<Byte> bytes, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytesArray = BytesConverter.toByteArray(bytes);

    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

    return BytesConverter.toByteList(cipher.update(bytesArray));
}
```

The problems is that `Cipher.update` in decryption mode returns empty byte array for the input which was encrypted by the `encrypt` method.

I'm confused. What's wrong?

Comment: Note that a `List<Byte>` will consume something like 16 times more memory than a byte array due to boxing.

Comment: @SLaks that depends on the implementation of `BytesConverter.toByteList` but I presume that either LinkedList or ArrayList is used and you would certainly be correct in those cases. And there is little to no reason to use a `List`. Look at `java.nio.ByteBuffer` if you require a wrapper.

Comment: @owlstead I just need sublist. That's why I use List.

Comment: And I counter with ByteBuffer.slice. Or just Arrays.copyOfRange of course, if the sublist is small. EXTRA Note that you can also just specify an offset and length in the update calls, there is no direct need to work outside a byte array if you don't want to use `ByteBuffer`. Note that the handling of `position` and `limit` within `ByteBuffer` takes some getting used to, read the API *well* if you go that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a call to `doFinal`. Due to padding for ECB and CBC mode encryption, `Cipher` instances are required to buffer up to a block size - 1 of bytes, which will only be padded and encrypted (or decrypted and unpadded) in the `doFinal()` call, which releases the last part of ciphertext (or plaintext for decryption).

What you should do is to use `"AES/ECB/NoPadding"` and only `doFinal` instead of `update` to *implement CBC* for each block (although just `update` may also work, but it is not 100% specified that it should). This is identical to block encrypt of the underlying AES cipher. You could also use the lower level, lightweight (i.e.: direct, non-JCE) API of Bouncy Castle, which provides AES *engines* which just implement the block cipher itself.

Comment: But if I try to encrypt full 16 byte block, it will add one more dummy block for next unpadd, right? So output will be 32 bytes (16 encrypted bytes + 16 dummy bytes). That's not what I want.

Comment: You can use CTR, but note that if you ever reuse the IV that you will likely lose all confidentiality. If you want to have the same size ciphertext without defining an IV you move into a part of crypto called "format preserving encryption". Also note that you usually need an authentication tag, e.g. by using GCM mode encryption, which also takes some bytes.

Comment: The above is general advice, I've updated the answer to indicate how to handle CBC mode.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't guess that `"AES/ECB/NoPadding"`is what I need.